# Automation testing tools for non-GUI installer written in Ruby script on Mac and Windows

Tags: automated-testing, ruby

I am finding an automation testing tool to test a non-GUI installer which is written in Ruby or power script. The automation tool should work on both windows and Mac machines.

Comment: If it's non GUI I assume it's a CLI installer, right? So what keeps you from starting it via a language of your choice and just check the generated output? I don't think you'd need a tool for that (or that a tool for that even exists).

Answer (score 1):

The classic tool for testing of interative non-GUI applications is called `expect`. It comes from the Tcl world but Ruby equivalents are available as well:

https://github.com/abates/ruby_expect